# How to stack the specific columns only in mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I am trying out bootstrap grid layout, where i need to stack the specific column only on mobile view.

e.g colA | colB | colC | colD | colE

desktop should be

`colA colB colC colD colE` - This is fine

mobile should be column C should be below column B.

```
colA colB colD colE
     colc
```

I have tried the below code, it woks fine for desktop as expected,

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-1">Col A</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2">Col B</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">Col C</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">Col D</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-2">Col E</div>
      </div>        
  </div>
```

when i view in mobile col C and the subsequent columns displays below col A. can anyone guide me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it as below :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">Col A</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">Col B</div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">Col C</div>                     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">Col D</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">Col E</div>

    </div>        
  </div>
```